# How to implement Custom Collapsable Toolbar in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Using **[this tutorial](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/)** to implement a Flexible Space pattern (the one with the collapsing toolbar).

I'm trying to achieve a similar effect as in the **Lollipop Contacts activity**, which at the beginning while entering the activity, views are only part of the image header:

[image]

Then, the user can scroll down the layout below the image in order to reveal more of it, until it reaches the maximum:

[image]

In my app, I can't manage to make it work.

What happens is that when entering the activity, the image header is presented at it's **maximum size, the size of the AppBarLayout, just as the layout above, and unlike in the Lollipop Contacts activity**, where it shows only part of the image.

This is the code that sets the height of the AppBarLayout (I want width of screen to be the maximum height):

```
int widthPx = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
AppBarLayout appbar = (AppBarLayout)findViewById(R.id.appbar);
appbar.setLayoutParams(new CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, widthPx));
```

And this is the code that sets the RecyclerView. Tried using scrollToPosition, thought it would lift the view of the RecyclerView up, but it has no effect at all:

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.activity_profile_bottom_recyclerview);

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    if(mAdapter == null){
        mAdapter = new ProfileAdapter(this, user, inEditMode);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1); // itemCount is 4
```

This is the layout xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_profile"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" // set programatically
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/header"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/activity_profile_bottom_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" /> 

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/navigation_view"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Note: If I manually scrolls down, the RecyclerView goes down and revealing more of the image, it just won't work through code.

I think scrollToPosition isn't the solution, does anyone have any idea?

Thought about using enterAlwaysCollapsed flag perhaps as [mentioned here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) in the CoordinatorLayout and Appbar section with minHeight:

> enterAlwaysCollapsed: When your view has declared a minHeight and you
>   use this flag, your View will only enter at its minimum height (i.e.,
>   ‘collapsed’), only re-expanding to its full height when the scrolling
>   view has reached its top.

So, I set scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed flag to my toolbar and minHeight in my RecyclerView, which didn't work. Then I tried moving the minHeight to other layouts such as AppBarLayout, nothing worked. It just shrank the image sometimes without the whole view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945667/set-initial-height-of-parallax-image-in-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Comment: Thanks @karaokyo, this actually worked. Still trying to figure out if there are other solutions as well.

Comment: @karaokyo could you check this out please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069081/scroll-behavior-of-flexible-space-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set initial height of parallax image in CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945667/set-initial-height-of-parallax-image-in-collapsingtoolbarlayout)

Comment: I would use MotionLayout to do this stuff. See examples on [https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/master/ConstraintLayoutExamples](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/master/ConstraintLayoutExamples)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069081/scroll-behavior-of-flexible-space-in-android I got a similar post, may be will help you out

Comment: Use Constarints layout for implement custom collapsable toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

The `AppBarComponent`provides a method called `.setExpanded(boolean expanded)`, which allows you to expand your `AppBarComponent`.

But keep in mind, that this method relies on this layout being a direct child of a `CoordinatorLayout`.

You can read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html#setExpanded(boolean)) for more information.

If you want to animate to a custom offset, try using the `setTopAndBottomOffset(int)` method.

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBar.getLayoutParams();
final AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
if (behavior != null) {
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt();
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            behavior.setTopAndBottomOffset((Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue());
            appBar.requestLayout();
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.setIntValues(0, -900);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(400);
    valueAnimator.start();
}
```