# Scroll behavior of Flexible Space in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

To prevent from re-posting all my code again, it can be found [in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260727/flexible-space-in-android)

What I'd like to do now, is to prevent the upper imageview from shrinking upon scrolling; instead, I'd like to make it 'static' so it won't scroll up and shrink when the lower view is scrolled over it.

I'll add some pictures to compensate for the loss of clarification.

This is how the screen looks at it's fullest size:

[image]

This is how it looks when it's shrinked:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Edit:
Forgot to mention what I tried and didn't work. Tried playing with the collapseMode of the ImageView which appears not related.
Also tried playing with the scrollFlags attribute of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, removing flags and adding enterAlways, but none worked. I have no clue on how to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simplest way would be to set the parallax multiplier to 1:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1" />
```